# top 1 row from User Defined Table Type

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-types

Is there a way to select top 1 row from 'User Defined Table Type' which is passed as a parameter to Stored Procedure?

```
CREATE TYPE t1 as TABLE
(
   id INT,
   name VARCHAR(100)
)
```

SP

```
CREATE STORED PROCEDURE sp1
(
    @type dbo.t1 as READONLY
)
BEGIN
   SELECT TOP 1 name FROM @type
END
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Select from @type not t1

Comment: Correcting the syntax errors and removing extraneous stuff, this will work: `CREATE PROCEDURE sp1
    @type dbo.t1 READONLY
AS
SELECT TOP 1 name FROM @type;`.  Note that `TOP` without `ORDER BY` may select any arbitrary row from the table; it is not deterministic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at below working example, which give detail idea about how to `CREATE/PASS/CALL` user defined Table Type from SP.

**User Defined Table Type Creation Script:**

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IdCenterIdList] AS TABLE(
    [Id] [varchar](36) NOT NULL,
    [CenterId] [varchar](36) NOT NULL
)
```

**SP Creation:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestType
    @IdCenterIdList AS IdCenterIdList ReadOnly
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        TOP(1) * 
    FROM @IdCenterIdList
END
GO
```

**SP Execute Statement:**

```
DECLARE @tblTestType IdCenterIdList 

INSERT INTO @tblTestType VALUES('11','1111')
,('22','222')
,('33','333')

EXEC TestType @tblTestType
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your stored procedure should probably be something like this:

```
CREATE STORED PROCEDURE sp1
(
    @type dbo.t1 READONLY
)
BEGIN
   SELECT TOP 1 name 
   FROM @type t1
   ORDER BY id
END
```

Notes:

1. I've removed the `as` keyword
2. using `TOP n` without using the `ORDER BY` clause will return a single row, but there is no guarantee what row it will be, since database tables are un sorted by nature.